# Gradle: need help to understand

Tags: gradle, task

Have in build.gradle

```
task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello World!'
    }
}

task count {
    println "one"
    doLast{
        4.times {print "$it "}
    }
    println "two"
    doFirst{
        2.times {println "$it - 1 "}
    }
    3.times {println( "$it -3")}
}

task intro(dependsOn: hello){
    doLast{
        println("I'm Gradle!")
    }
}
```

run in shell

```
gradle intro
```

and get

```
one
two
0 -3
1 -3
2 -3
:hello
Hello World!
:intro
I'm Gradle!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

but it's not correct!!!
the correct output is

```
:hello
Hello World!
:intro
I'm Gradle!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

What did I do wrong?

ps
adding details to because there is too much code here :(
adding details to because there is too much code here :(
adding details to because there is too much code here :(
adding details to because there is too much code here :(

Comment: Why do you think that what you get is not correct? (somehow it is correct by definition because it is what gradle does). ps. the answer to this question would make a useful replacement for your filler text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it's wrong? Probably it is absolutely correct. This is all due to configuration of the build. Read about it in the [official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).

There are a number of phases take place during the build. One of them is configuration phase. All the output you don't expect to see - is the configuration's output. When you do something in task's closure, it's executed at the configuration of your build, untill you place it into the `doLast` or `doFirst` closure to run at the execution phase (or task's closure is declared with `<<` that's the same as `doLast`).

Note that configuration is executed for all tasks, no matter if they will be executed or not. That is the reason of your unexpected output - it's just done as a part of your build configuration, though they are declared within some task.

Comment: spasibo, Stanislav!